# How to merge records joined on different ids in four tables mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine data of different libraries which are using different mysql databases with similar table structure on the same server. Each library has two tables with the following structure:

Library1

```
Table1: books (id, title, isbn, publisher, city....)
Table2: toc (id, chapter, book_id)
```

Library2

```
Table1: books (id, title, isbn, publisher, city....)
Table2: toc (id, chapter, book_id)
```

..... and so on

I get the chapters of a book by joining books and toc table on id and book_id respectively.

I can copy the books table of both libraries using something like

```
insert into library1.books select * from library2.books
```

However, I cannot copy the "toc" table of both libraries using the above method as both toc tables could have same book_id.

So my question is how I can copy the toc table from library2 to library1 adding new book_id to newly added records of toc table of library1

Comment: the first thing that comes to mind is why have you different tables in the first place a normalized design with only 1 book table, second make id a uuid and then you can union all you want, but that would still have multiple books with the same name or isbn, but that isn't that much of a problem to eliminate duplicates

Comment: Different tables are necessary as a book can have multiple chapters (thousands in case of encyclopedias or dictionaries).

Comment: no, your design should be a book table with all books, a library table (general information) and a bridge table between library and books the toc tables must have the id of the bridge table and chapter and verse with a further user_id you can idividualize the chapters of the bool

Comment: Now I got it thank you. It will surely solve the problem.